# Is it possible to use "my" instead of "am I" in "Where am I going to put my belongings?"?

Tags: sentence-construction

Instead of "Where am I going to put my belongings?" is it possible to say "Where my going to put my belongings?"

Comment: No, "my" shows possession while "am" shows action or state.

Answer (score 1):

No.

My is not an abbreviation for "am I".

In Old English "My" and "Mine" were the same word, (min) But by 1200 a reduced form "mi" later "my" was used when the next word started with a consonant. And by 1500 "my" was used for all words. It is completely unrelated to "am I", which in Old English would have been "eom ic"

In some dialects, "am I" can be slurred and might sound like my.

> Wher'm I gonna put my belongings.

This is typical of casual speech in some dialects, but would not normally be a style that learners should try to copy.

Answer (score 0):

'Where my' is not correct here.

In fast, informal speech, native English speakers often pronounce words smaller and shorter, and run them together, so they can be heard as something else. 'Where am I' might be spoken as 'Wherea mI', which could be heard as 'Where my'.